# strcpy in Symbian?

Tags: c++, symbian

I am looking for a strcpy equivalent in Symbian. I do not wanna use the strcpy
function from stdlib.

Here is what I wanna do:

```
char name[128];
TBuf8 aName = _L("Test");

strncpy( name, aName.Ptr(), 127 );
*( name + MAX_FILENAME_LEN ) = 0;
```

So basically I wanna copy a TBuf8 to an char array. Is there a proper way to do that
in Symbian? aName has to be of type char!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
TInt size = aName.Size() <= 127 ? aName.Size() : 127;
Mem::Copy(name, aName.Ptr(), size);
name[size] = 0;
```

But beware that on unicode builds, `TBuf8` strings are hard to come by, so there may be more to it than this.

Answer (score 1):

```
char name[128];
TBuf8 name_buf = _L("Test");
TPtr8 name_ptr = TPtr8(name,sizeof(name));
name_ptr = aName;
name_ptr.ZeroTerminate(); //if it supposed to be a zeroterminated string.
```

All text processing in symbian is easier if you learn to think in descriptors.

The ZeroTerminate call should obviously not be used if the TBuf8 contains binary data.